# Got my first project idea, am I on the right track?

Tags: php, mysql, project

I'm 14 and I am teaching myself PHP. I am going to build a parts database for my dads lawn mower repair store.

Each lawnmower has 'OEM' numbers, but the OEM parts are expensive. My dad has suppliers who make parts which are compatible with these OEM parts and in the back of the catalogues there are charts of OEM to the catalogs part number

I want to be able to enter the OEM number into a search field and then bring up every compatible catalog part number along with which catalog its from... I hope this is clear.

Right now I have extracted the data from the catalogs and have 6 database tables like this

```
id    |    oem     |     partnumber
------+------------+----------------------
      |            |
```

The table name is the catalog name.

I have a little coding experience (played around with arduinos and raspberry pi's for a while) so I have a little knowledge but never done anything with databases. I also know html and css, and a tiny bit of javascript.

**I see these as the steps:**

1. get OEM number from the search field.
2. search every table for the OEM
3. If there is a match return the part number and catalog
4. if there is no match display 'nothing found'

I kind of get it in my head, but I am totally lost in searching many tables with 1 query.... I can't do it with 'one' query because I need the catalog name (the table name) to be returned too... the easy option would be to make 1 table but I want to update this in the future and that would make it very hard.

I think I have to set the table names as an array and loop through the array running the query, but I can't get my head around how I would do this???

How exactly would you go about this?

Am I doing it wrong?

I could do many queries I guess but I was always taught that repeating code usually means you are doing it wrong, so I don't want to do that. I want to learn properly...

many thanks

Comment: Why not just have one table and add a `catalog_id` column? And then another table with the catalog info related to the part number table?

Comment: Careful there - sounds like you made a table for each catalog and not just a relational structure where you have 1 catalog table, and 1 parts table where the parts have a field for the catalog ID.

Comment: ^Exactly, I suggest that you design it on a paper then implement it. You should have a table for each real life object (ex: ITEM). Plus if needed a table for many to many relationships

Comment: Good luck son! Daddy is proud of you

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.  You might want to do a thing called normalisation in the database world.  It basically means if you have something that is reference alot i.e. OEM, Catalog etc you might pull that out into a separate table and then you can reference it's id rather than value and thus you avoid duplication.

SQL is built for this kind of query (if you are interested you should look at set based logic and venn diagrams that will help in understanding sql).

So you might have a query that looks like this

```
SELECT 
  p.PartNumber,
  p.Price,
  c.Name
FROM 
  Parts p
INNER JOIN
  OEM oem
ON
  p.OEMId = oem.id
INNER JOIN
  Catalog c
ON
 c.Id = oem.CatalogId
WHERE
  oem.slug = 'OEM123ABC'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong. Put the catalog name in the table, if that's all there is to it. Then you do can do a SQL query like:

```
SELECT part_number FROM table_name WHERE catalog='catalog_name' AND oem='search_term';
```

Make sure to set the appropriate indices.